# How to completely turn off implicit network usage in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.29.0
- OS Version: macOS Mojave 10.14.1
- Little Snitch in Alert Mode
- Fresh user profile for VSCode without any installed extensions
- User settings:

```js
{
    "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false,
    "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "extensions.showRecommendationsOnlyOnDemand": true,
    "git.autofetch": false,
    "npm.fetchOnlinePackageInfo": false,
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": true,
    "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
    "update.channel": "none",
    "update.showReleaseNotes": false,
    "workbench.enableExperiments": false,
    "workbench.settings.enableNaturalLanguageSearch": false,
    "workbench.statusBar.feedback.visible": false,
}
```

Even after all these settings, when I open VSCode, it tries to connect to `az764295.vo.msecnd.net` and `dc.services.visualstudio.com`. How to completely turn off implicit network usage?

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61646).

In addition to those settings, try starting VS Code using the flags `code --disable-extensions --disable-telemetry`.

- `--disable-telemetry` should prevent `dc.services.visualstudio.com` from being accessed.
- `--disable-extensions` should prevent `az764295.vo.msecnd.net` from being accessed. The endpoint is used for getting a list of malicious extensions and for extension recommendations.